# Force if a diver is lifting a pillar out of the water?(High school physics)

Tags: forces, density, buoyancy

A diver is searching through the remains of an old shipwreck at a depth of 45 m below the surface of the ocean.

The diver finds a marble pillar that is approximately 1.7 m x 0.15 m x 0.15 m in dimension. The diver uncovers it and begins to lift it very slowly.

**(A) How much force is required for the diver to lift the pillar at a constant speed? Ignore viscosity.**

The diver decides it is too far to lift the pillar on his own. He attaches a hoisting cable from his boat to the pillar. The cable lifts the pillar very slowly through the water.

**(B) Ignoring viscosity, how does the tension in the hoisting cable compare to the force you calculated in part (A)?**

---

For part A, I calculated the diver would need to apply about 65kg of force.
 (Volume X Density of marble)-(Volume X Density of Saltwater)

**What I don't understand is why the tension on the cable would be any different.**